# не могу передать массив php в js в wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

я формирую большой массив из постороннего API в js хочу что бы при вводе имени происходил сразу поиск совпадений по буквам для этого использую jquery-ui autocomplete, вот мне надо этот масив дать на обработку этому виджету в js, и вот я столкнулся с такой банальной проблемой что не могу передать данные для обработки в виджет. 
Вот код php:

```
$flowers = array("Астра", "Нарцисс", "Роза", "Пион", "Примула",
                 "Подснежник", "Мак", "Первоцвет", "Петуния", "Фиалка");
$json = json_encode($flowers);
echo $json;
```

Вот код js:

```
 var name = ('<?php echo $json;?>');
  alert(name);//должно вывести обьект а выводит так '<?php echo $json;?>'
```

Как мне получить данные вот в таком формате?:

```
 var value = [
                    "C",
                    "C++",
                    "Java",
                    "JavaScript",
                    "PHP",
                    "Python",
                    "Ruby",
                ];
```

Не пойму может у wordpress надо как то иначе, подскажите пожалуйста кто знает

Comment: Это просто катастрофа... то что вы написали, может стоит вам начать изучать PHP заново ?  зачем вы Array переводите в JSON ? с чего вы взяли что после получение JSON- a в нутри будет Object  (должно вывести обьект) ?? по какой причине вы , этого бедного JSOn засунули в кавычки в JS ? вы хоть понимаете ваши действия ? Даже если я тут вам напишу готовое решение по вашему вопросу, вы просто ничего не поймёте, скопируете код ответа и всё.

Comment: что значит зачем array в json??в примере так! и слушайте не надо критики, если у вас есть знания которые могли бы мне помочь то излагайте, то что там есть что то лишнее то просто скопировалась из черновика, и я все понимаю что там и для чего там, если знаете как надо давайте пример, а критиками могут быть все

Comment: )) классный ответ )) вместо того чтобы задуматься о бытие, понять всю серьёзность ситуации (не знания PHP и JS), подумать о том как начать изучать данные языки, вы просто хамите )) это назывется синдром Wordpress. Ну удачи
ЗЫ да кстаит в UI autocomplete передаются данные в JS array - а объект это другое. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Вы ждали от меня профессиональных знаний php и js?я всего лишь школьник который делает домашку, извините меня о великий гуру php и js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился с помощью wp_localize_script

Comment: Дайте более подробный ответ. Потом, если ответ полностью решил проблемиу вашего  вопроса, мможете отметить его как принятый.